# Chain link vrf - recover callback address from proof

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, chainlink

Is there any way to tell what the callback address will be from a proof?

I want to monitor all fulfill request transactions in the pending pool which are being generated  where the callback is a specific contract, so I need to somehow recover the callback contract from the proof in the transaction input.

Comment: Could you provide more details? Code examples, screenshots, etc. Your question is not that clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get that info from the proof itself, this is what the proof looks like:

```js
  struct Proof {
    uint256[2] pk;
    uint256[2] gamma;
    uint256 c;
    uint256 s;
    uint256 seed;
    address uWitness;
    uint256[2] cGammaWitness;
    uint256[2] sHashWitness;
    uint256 zInv;
  }
```

You will need to create an off-chain script to monitor particular events from particular contracts to do this.